# how to use a viewModel to update the list of a recyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm trying to display the history of results of a TicTacToe game using Android (kotlin). So I've in my gameViewModel I tried to make a LiveData called resultsLists as a repository as a List of the score of each player in each game and I stored new entries to this repository whenever there's a win or draw case and I observed it in my GameHistoryFragment, I'm not sure if it's okay to do that.Thanks for the help!
here's the code for the GameViewModel and and the GameHistoryFragment.

[image: GameFragment]
[image: GameViewModel]
[image: GameViewModel]
[image: GameHistoryAdapter]

Comment: Please don’t post pictures of code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please update your question with code not with Images!